# Is there a way to get the rank of each player?

Tags: java, compare

- I'm a bit confused on how to get the rank of each player. I created an integer array of ranks because I thought it would make it easier to compare, but I'm lost on how to compare the ranks given in the String.
- For rank 1, "A of suit" is printed out
- rank 11 -> "J of suit"
- rank 12 -> "Q of suit"
- rank 13 -> "K of suit"
- Is there a way to get the rank of the rankString printed out?
- War method that creates two player arrays, attempting to compare here, but unsure how to get the rank.

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    
    public class War {
    
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        CardDeck deck = new CardDeck();

    
        int size = deck.Deck().size();
    
        ArrayList player1 = new ArrayList<>(deck.Deck().subList(0, (size) / 2));
        ArrayList player2 = new ArrayList<>(deck.Deck().subList((size) / 2, size));

    
        System.out.println("Player 1: " + player1.get(0));
        System.out.println("Player 2: " + player2.get(0));
```

CardDeck method: creates the deck and shuffles it

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.List;
    
    public class CardDeck extends War{
    public int rank;

      private String suit, rankString;
    
    
      public List<String> Deck() {
        String[] cardSuit = {"Hearts", "Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds"};
         int[] cardRank = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13};
    
        String[] deck = new String[52];
    
        for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
          rank = cardRank[i%13];
          suit = cardSuit[i/13];
    
          switch(rank){
            case 1 :
              rankString = "A";
              deck[i] = rankString + " of " + suit;
              break;
            case 11 :
              rankString = "J";
              deck[i] = rankString + " of " + suit;
              break;
            case 12 :
              value = 12;
              rankString = "Q";
              deck[i] = rankString + " of " + suit;
              break;
            case 13 :
              rankString = "K";
              deck[i] = rankString + " of " + suit;
              break;
            default:
              deck[i] = rank + " of " + suit;
    
          }
        }
    
    
        List<String> deckList = Arrays.asList(deck);
    
        Collections.shuffle(deckList);
        return deckList;
      }
    
    }
```

I've only been working with Java for a little bit and am confused on how creating a separate getRank method works

Edit: By Rank, I mean the integer of the card value. So for A of Suit, I want to get back 1, 2=2...J=11, Q=12,K=13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've confused yourself. Your class is named `CardDeck`. Which suggests it represents **an entire deck of cards**. A deck of cards *does not* have a rank and does not have a suit. I don't go to the store and buy a pack of cards that contains only 52 ace of spades, of course.

It's a single card, *that* has a rank and a suit.

Your `Deck()` method returns a list of strings. This is not object oriented.

I suggest you do the following:

- Make a class called `Card`. It has fields for rank and suit. I suggest you make these enums (`enum Suit { SPADES, HEARTS, CLUBS, DIAMONDS; }` and `enum Rank { ACE, TWO, THREE, .., JACK, QUEEN, KING;}`, but if you haven't covered that yet, you can stick with `int`. There is no need to have a third field with the string representation, you can and should calculate that every time (it's a computer and it can do a few billion of those a second. The memory lookup would be slower than calculating it, if you are going to make a point of performance).
- Add useful methods to Card. Certainly a `public String toString() {}` which calculates a nice string representation based on the rank and suit (this would be where `rankString + " of " + suit` is going to go).
- Now make a class called `CardDeck`. It has a single field (`List<Card>`). Create a method called `reshuffle()` which clears the list, then generates all 52 cards, then invokes `shuffleRemaining()` on itself. Write `shuffleRemaining()` which simply shuffles the list as is.
- Give it a constructor, which calls `reshuffle()` on itself - now `new CardDeck()` gets you a shuffled, 52-card deck.
- Add more methods. `draw()`, for example, which does something like `return list.remove(0);` - removes the 'top' card and returns it.